# Group by with Inner join doesn't return any result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 6 *
from vws_entryline el
inner join vws_customer c on el.GeneralAccountNumber = c.AccountNumber
group by el.VoucherNumber
```

I have a table `vws_entryline` associated to the table `vws_customer` according to the account number of the customers, as you can see. I would want to group the results by another field, `VoucherNumber` (which is present in `vws_entryline` only).

For example, I would want to have these results (it's not JSON format, only an example from my mind that doesn't correspond exactly to a group by... but what I want is actually a SQL group by result):

> {AccountNumber: "PO200", field_1_vws_customer: "foo", 
>   GeneralAccountNumber: "PO200", "VoucherNumber": "N45PO",
>   field_1_vws_entryline: 150.25},
>
> {AccountNumber: "PO200",
>   field_1_vws_customer: "foo",  GeneralAccountNumber: "PO200",
>   "VoucherNumber": "N45PO", field_1_vws_entryline: 25.75},
>
> {AccountNumber: "PO200", field_1_vws_customer: "foo", 
>   GeneralAccountNumber: "PO200", "VoucherNumber": "AZERTY",
>   field_1_vws_entryline: 50,50},
>
> {AccountNumber: "SW7",
>   field_1_vws_customer: "foo",  GeneralAccountNumber: "SW7",
>   "VoucherNumber": "42HaveAGoodDay24", field_1_vws_entryline: 50,50}

As you can see, the results are correctly grouped by the `VoucherNumber` field.

However, my SQL request doesn't return any result. Why?

## Edit

I've tried:

```
SELECT el.EntryLineDate, el.VoucherNumber, el.label, el.GeneralAccountNumber,
       el.Debit, el.Credit, el.type, el.amount, el.PaymentTypeid, el.EntryNumber,
       c.ThirdId, c.civility, c.name, c.NaturalPerson, c.ThirdLanguage, c.siren,
       c.nic, c.naf, c.AccountNumber
from vws_entryline el
inner join vws_customer c on el.GeneralAccountNumber = c.AccountNumber
group by el.VoucherNumber
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: This query will fail on SQL server because the variables in the select are not all in the group by clause (and you have no aggregation functions) and it will fail in MySQL because it doesn't support `TOP`.

Comment: @Nick I don't really see what to do, what are the select variables to put in the group by clause? I would be happy to upvote&accept your answer if you would write one! - NB: `group by` seems to exist in SQLServer (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Two different products, having somewhat incompatible SQL implementations.)

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server :)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have aggregation on voucher Number in the JSON resultset. It appears as a normal JSON document with every row for every voucher number.

As you have not provided schema, below is rough query. You need to use FOR JSON clause to achieve JSON resultset. [Read more on FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT v_c.AccountNumber, field_1_vws_customer,GeneralAccountNumber, 
VoucherNumber, field_1_vws_entryline
FROM vws_entryline AS v_e
JOIN vws_customer AS v_c
ON v_e.accountNumber = v_c.accountNumber
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Comment: Sorry! I have edited the OP to precise that it's not real results, just something I've imaginated. But my `VoucherNumber` are, in this order: N45PO, N45PO, AZERTY, 42HaveAGoodDay24. So my (imaginated) results are correctly "grouped" by the vouchernumber

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
SELECT TOP 6 c.AccountNumber,field_1_vws_customer,el.GeneralAccountNumber,el.VoucherNumber,
field_1_vws_entryline from vws_entryline el inner join vws_customer c on el.GeneralAccountNumber = c.AccountNumber group by c.AccountNumber,field_1_vws_customer,el.GeneralAccountNumber,el.VoucherNumber,
field_1_vws_entryline
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem, however, is that you precise a lot of fields in the select clause. I really want to use  `select top 6 *` (`*`) . So I've tried: `SELECT TOP 6 *, el.VoucherNumber from vws_entryline el inner join vws_customer c on el.GeneralAccountNumber = c.AccountNumber group by el.VoucherNumber` but it doesn't work

Comment: Yes.. If you try select id,name from table group by id....will give you error because you haven't selected all columns mentioned in select list to group by. But if you try select id,name from table group by id,name will work.

Comment: It's weird, I'hve tried this but doesn't work: `SELECT el.EntryLineDate, el.VoucherNumber, el.label, el.GeneralAccountNumber, el.Debit, el.Credit, el.type, el.amount, el.PaymentTypeid, el.EntryNumber, c.ThirdId, c.civility, c.name, c.NaturalPerson, c.ThirdLanguage, c.siren, c.nic, c.naf, c.AccountNumber from vws_entryline el inner join vws_customer c on el.GeneralAccountNumber = c.AccountNumber group by el.VoucherNumber`

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler - select * 
from vws_entryline el inner join vws_customer c 
on el.GeneralAccountNumber = c.AccountNumber
order by vouchernumber